# Every k-th digit cyclic problem using strings in C

Tags: c, string, algorithm, numbers

Given some number in a form of string, I want to extract every k-th number from it. Then I go through the remaining string and extract every k-th number again. The thing I get as a result should be the number formed by these extracted ones(in a proper order). Example: 123456789, k = 3  --> 369485271

My algorithm is as follows: While the lenght of the string allows extracting every k-th number, I go through the string and store every k-th element in another string. Then I delete the extracted elements from the original string by tracking the proper index of an element and proceed forvard while the lenght of my str is sufficient.
I can't figure out what's the problem with my code. And maybe my approach isn't that good and there are some better/simpler ways of diong this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
void remove(char *str, unsigned int index) {
    char *src;
    for (src = str+index; *src != '\0'; *src = *(src+1),++src) ;
    *src = '\0';
}
int main() {
    char number[100];
    char result[100];
    int k;
    printf("Enter a string: ");
    scanf("%s",number);
    printf("Enter a key: ");
    scanf("%d",&k);
    while (strlen(number)>k-1) {
        for (int i = 0, p = 0; number[i] != '\0'; i++) {
            if (i % k == (k-1)) {
                result[p] = number[i];
                p++;
            }
        }
        for (int j = 0; number[j] != '\0'; j++){
            if (j % k == (k-1)) {
                remove(number, j);
                j+=1;  /*since the index was shifted due to removing an element*/
            }
        }
    }
puts(result);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: What would that mean? "if I run it separately during the first iteration of while cycle I got a bunch of errors." What do you men by "run it separately" and what errors do you get?

Comment: What's "a bunch of errors"? Please be more specific, and paste the exact error messages that you get. See also [What Do You Mean "It Doesn't Work"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147616/what-do-you-mean-it-doesnt-work)

Comment: Your example indicates that you want to get all digits in the final result. Then you should not stop if that is false: `while (strlen(number)>k-1)`

Comment: @Stef i just realized what these errors were about. Probably I should delete that part

Comment: @Gerhardh I see your point. But how else can I specify the terminating point in there, so that I gat all the numbers

Comment: @Ostap Did you test your function `remove` separately to check that it does what you want it to do? If you test it with `str="123456789"` and `index=3`, what result do you expect, and what result do you get?

Comment: You can only get all digits if you run until there are no more left in the input. You must update your loop(s) to handle any length of remaining input.

Comment: Now after you removed that last part, what is your question? Do you get incorrect result, what result? What did you excpet? For what input?

Comment: @Gerhardh I wrote what I expect and for what input. I get 3 symbols. For 123456789 and k = 3 I get 889

Comment: @MBo I see. I need to check if an element is already in result string rather than delete added elements from the original string

Comment: OK, I missed "cyclic"

Comment: `"889"` is `"369"` overwritten by `"48"` overwritten again by `"8"`. You start `p` from 0 again in each iteration of `while` loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You some issues:

- You start writing your output from scratch again in each iteration of your `while` loop.
- You do not handle the last digits
- You do not treat the input as a cyclic input.
- You do not terminate your output string.
- `remove` is already a name of standard library function.

A shorter version could be this (untested):

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
void remove_digit(char *str, unsigned int index) {
    char *src;
    for (src = str+index; *src != '\0'; *src = *(src+1),++src)
        ;
}
int main() {
    char number[100];
    char result[100];
    int k;
    printf("Enter a string: ");
    scanf("%s",number);
    printf("Enter a key: ");
    scanf("%d",&k);
    int p = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int skip = k-1; // We remove 1 digit and skip k-1 digits
    while (number[0] != 0) {
        i = (i + skip) % strlen(number);
        result[p] = number[i];
        p++;
        remove_digit(number, i);
    }
    number[p] = 0;
    puts(result);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code seems to be what you want:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void remove_(char *str, unsigned int index) {
    char *src;
    for (src = str+index; *src != '\0'; *src = *(src+1),++src) ;
    *src = '\0';
}
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    char number[100];
    char result[100];
    int tmp[100];
    int k;
    printf("Enter a string: ");
    scanf("%s",number);
    printf("Enter a key: ");
    scanf("%d",&k);
    
    int p = 0;
    for (int tp = 0; strlen(number) > k-1; tp = 0) {
        for (int i = 0; number[i] != '\0'; i++)
            if (i % k == (k-1))result[p++] = number[i];
        
        for (int j = 0; number[j] != '\0'; j++)
            if (j % k == (k-1)) tmp[tp++] = j;
        
        for (; tp; --tp) remove_(number, tmp[tp-1]);
    }
    
    // The newly added code
    for (int index; strlen(number); ) {
        index = (k-1) % strlen(number);
        result[p++] = number[index];
        remove_(number, index);
    }

    puts(result);
    return 0;
}
```

The most important thing is that every while loop, you need to remove the elements in `number` at once. While ensuring the integrity of your original code, I made some changes. Unfortunately, the main idea of ​​the original code is wrong.

It should circulate from the tail (including the rest) to the head after one round. But I found that the function of the code you provided is that after each round, the next round starts from the 0th element of the head.

By the way, your algorithm is similar to the [Josephus problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josephus_problem)

Comment: It matches with what's needed in the beginning, but overall it even outputs a number with smaller number of digits than in original number

Comment: @Ostap there is the same error `while (strlen(number)>k-1)` as with your code. There must be some digits missing.